# Macports cgal not working! How do I fix it?

Tags: c++, c, macports, cgal

This is a basic example that I found on the CGAL main webpage. I am trying to compile the following:

```
  1 #include <iostream>                                                             
  2 #include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>                 
  3 #include <CGAL/convex_hull_2.h>                                                 
  4                                                                                 
  5 typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;                  
  6 typedef K::Point_2 Point_2;                                                     
  7                                                                                 
  8 int main()                                                                      
  9 {                                                                               
 10   Point_2 points[5] = { Point_2(0,0), Point_2(10,0), Point_2(10,10), Point_2(6,5), Point_2(4,1) };
 11   Point_2 result[5];                                                            
 12                                                                                 
 13   Point_2 *ptr = CGAL::convex_hull_2( points, points+5, result );               
 14   std::cout <<  ptr - result << " points on the convex hull" << std::endl;      
 15   return 0;                                                                     
 16 }
```

but I get this error:

```
Demo $> make
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/helloworld_cgal.dir/helloworld_cgal.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/local/include/CGAL/Bbox_2.h:30,
                 from /opt/local/include/CGAL/basic_classes.h:30,
                 from /opt/local/include/CGAL/Cartesian/Cartesian_base.h:28,
                 from /opt/local/include/CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h:27,
                 from /opt/local/include/CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h:27,
                 from /Users/carlos/Documents/Code/Demo/helloworld_cgal.cpp:2:
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h:81: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘...’ token
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h:81: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘...’ token
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h:83: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h:84: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h:84: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Args’ with no type
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h: In function ‘int CGAL::make_array(const T&, int)’:
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h:86: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h:86: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘=’ token
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h:86: error: ‘args’ was not declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h:86: error: expected `}' before ‘...’ token
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h:86: error: expected `}' before ‘...’ token
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h:86: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘...’ token
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h: At global scope:
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h:87: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘return’
/opt/local/include/CGAL/array.h:88: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/helloworld_cgal.dir/helloworld_cgal.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/helloworld_cgal.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I installed cgal using macports. Does anyone know what could be wrong with
this?

Comment: Please post your code inline instead of on pastebin. The same goes for errors.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know it supported inline code. Let me know if you know how to fix it...

Comment: It may be that the compiler used in macport to build CGAL is not the one used to compile your example. The error you have is that variadic template parameters are not supported by your compiler while CGAL was configured with them.

Comment: Would it be possible to have macports compile with the same compiler as the one I am using to compile my sample?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it looks like a mismatch between compiler or compiler options used when building CGAL and compiling with CGAL.  It may be that macports doesn't help, I have been luckier with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) than macports when installing CGAL.